# mysql get all records when looking for duplicates

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, duplicate-data

I want to make a report of all the entries in a table where one column has duplicate entries.  Let's assume we have a table like this:

```
customer_name     | some_number
Tom                 1
Steve               3
Chris               4
Tim                 3
...
```

I want to show all the records that have `some_number` as a duplicate.  I have used a query like this to show all the duplicate records:

```
select customer_name, some_number from table where some_number in (select some_number from table group by some_number having count(*) > 1) order by some_number;
```

This works for a small table, but the one I actually need to operate on is fairly large.  30,000 + rows and it is taking FOREVER!  Does someone have a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM (SELECT some_number, COUNT(*) AS nb
       FROM your_table
       GROUP BY some_number
       HAVING nb>1
     ) t2, your_table t1
WHERE t1.some_number=t2.some_number
```

The query first uses `GROUP BY` to find duplicate records, then joins with the table to retrieve all fields.
Since `HAVING` is used, it will return only the records you are interested in, then do the join with `your_table`.

Be sure your table has an index on `some_number` if you want the query to be fast.

Comment: I added an explanation why doing this way is faster.

Answer (score 1):

Does this perform better? It joins on a table of `some_number` counts and then filters to include only those with a `count` > 1.

```
SELECT t.customer_name, t.some_number 
FROM my_table t
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT some_number, COUNT(*) AS ct
  FROM my_table
  GROUP BY some_number ) dup ON t.some_number = dup.some_number
 WHERE dup.ct > 1
```